# How can insert into rest request a body part?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I'm building a simple rest client to call rest web service.
Now, I want to call a Post rest web service and I want put into body this structure:

```
<component>
   <section>
      Etc.
   </section>
</component>
```

So I have this code but I'm not able to put this structure data into body section.

```
public void writeSectionIntoCCD(String appID, String shardSecret, String userID, String password, String templateID)
{
    String currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    String URL = "https://sitoweb.it/APPName/";
    var client = new RestClient(URL);
    // client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
    string hash = CalculateMD5Hash(currentTime + shardSecret + password);
    var request = new RestRequest("resource/ccd/" + userID + "/" + appID + "/" + currentTime + "/" + hash + "/replace_section?" + templateID, Method.POST);
    var body = "<component><section>Etc.</section></component>";

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}
```